# OpenOffice.org 3 waits 25 seconds before opening

Tags: linux, fedora, openoffice, hostname

I'm on Fedora 14, and OpenOffice 3.3.0 takes a long time to open (about 30 seconds, sometimes less).  It isn't a CPU or disk performance issue, it's just simply a very long delay before the program opens.  It appears to be a frivolous network connection timing out.

According to Wireshark, it tries to look up:

```
dulcimer.(none)
```

which fails, after which it tries to look up:

```
dulcimer.(none).mylitestream.com
```

(`dulcimer` is my hostname, and [LiteStream](http://litestream.net) is my ISP)

Is there a way to work around this bug in OpenOffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my hostname from `dulcimer` to `dulcimer.none`, as suggested on [another webpage](http://cqlug.linux.org.au/node/66).

### How to change your hostname on Ubuntu:

Edit `/etc/hostname`, and change it from:

```
yourhostname
```

to:

```
yourhostname.none
```

You also need to edit `/etc/hosts`, changing any occurrences of `yourhostname` to `yourhostname.none` .

Then, reboot.  Actually, you can get away with not rebooting by typing:

```
sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname
```

### How to change your hostname on Fedora:

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/network`, and change the `HOSTNAME` setting:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=yourhostname
```

to:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=yourhostname.none
```

You don't have to edit `/etc/hosts` like you do on Ubuntu, as it is updated automagically.

Then, reboot.  Actually, I think you can get away with not rebooting by typing:

```
su -c 'hostname yourhostname.none'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add that address to your hosts file make it point to 127.0.0.1 and also, disable java from the settings menu, it adds to the opening time.

Comment: P.S.:  I want to accept this answer because it's simpler and easier than mine, but your answer wouldn't be easy to understand for someone who doesn't know what "your hosts file" is.  Could you clarify?  Thanks.